# Number of arrangements of five 0's and six 1's.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many arrangements of five 0's and six 1's are there with no consecutive 1's?

I found this question in a book named Challenge and thrill of pre college mathematics ;
My solving goes like fixing the places of 0's and filling 1 Between the 6 places -
"*0_0_0_0_0*"
But i dunno how to obtain the value , i would be grateful for any hint or solutions.

Comment: Sry but i am unable to add _ at the extreme ends of my solution

Comment: Place the $6$ ones with gaps between them. Each gap between two ones must have at least one zero, but that requires $5$ zeroes, so there is only the one way.

Answer (score 2):

10101010101 is the only arrangement of 6 1's, 5 zeros, and no consecutive 1's.
Essentially every 1, must be at the beginning, the end, or be in a ...010... pattern.